# How to make list comprehension to extract tuples to 2 different lists?

Tags: python-2.7, list, sorting, coordinates

In given code, I am extracting first column from data_points list which contains a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary contain a tuple of (x,y) coordinates.  I extract minX and minY from the keys. How can I compress the code?

```
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    keys = data_points[0].keys()
    for i in keys:
        x_list.append(i[0])
        y_list.append(i[1]) 

    min_value = (min(x_list), min(y_list))
```

Comment: I do not think this is dupe of the listed post, which is why I listed that post in my response, but did not mark this as a dupe of same.  OP needs to separate a list of tuples.  Question wasn't clear on that, but that is what the code shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can be used to combine, as well as, separate lists/tuples.  You did not give any sample data so I will assume:

```
data_points = [{
    (3, 0): None,
    (1, 2): None,
}]
keys = data_points[0].keys()
```

A one line equivalent to your code which splits the tuples and gets the mins is:

```
min_value = (min(zip(*keys)[0]), min(zip(*keys)[1]))
```

There are some caveats with zip in python 2 and its creation of potentially large intermediate structures.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python/1663826?s=2%7C0.0000#1663826) for some more info.